# specifying type of a class member in template function

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I have this template function:

```
template <class P>
double Determinant(const P & a, const P & b, const P & c) {
    return  (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (c.x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y);
}
```

but I want to avoid forcing the return type to `double` all the time -- P::x and P::y could be ints too, and I need this function in both situations. Is there a way to specify the type of x and y, something like this?

```
//doesn't compile; can't deduce template argument for T
template <typename T, class P>
T Determinant(const P & a, const P & b, const P & c) {
    return  (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (c.x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y);
}
```

edit: My compiler is VC2005

edit2: sorry to forget to mention: Unfortunately I can't modify the implementation of the structs for P; one of the point types I deal with is MFC/ATL's CPoint, which are hard-coded as `{ long x; long y; }`.

Comment: Which compiler(s) are you using?

Comment: vc2005 - edited into the question now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiler cannot deduce return-type of function template, from function argument. Type deduction is done with function arguments only.

In C++03, you can define *typedef* in your class as:

```
struct A //suppose A is going to be type argument to your function template
{
   int x, y;     //I'm assuming type of x and y is same!
   typedef int value_type; //type of x and y!
};
```

And then you've to re-write your function as:

```
template <class P>
typename P::value_type Determinant(const P & a, const P & b, const P & c) {
    return  (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (c.x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y);
}
```

Notice the return-type now, its a dependent type. Its :

```
typename P::value_type
```

The keyword `typename` is required here.

---

Alright, as you said you can't modify your structs, then you can use traits instead. Here is how this can be done:

```
template<typename T> struct PTraits;

//Suppose this is your type which you can't modify
struct A //A is going to be type argument to your function template
{
   long x, y; 
};

//specialization: defining traits for struct A
template<>
struct PTraits<A>
{
    typedef long value_type; //since type of A::x and A::y is long!
};
```

And your function template would look like this:

```
template <class P>
typename PTraits<P>::value_type Determinant(const P & a, const P & b, const P & c) {
    return  (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (c.x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y);
}
```

Notice the return-type; its slightly different now:

```
typename PTraits<P>::value_type
```

Again, `value_type` is a dependent name, so the keyword `typename` is required.

Note that you've to specialize `PTraits<>` for each type which you pass to the function template, as I did.

Comment: neat trick Nawaz; haven't thought of that before.  Unfortunately I can't modify the implementation of the struct; one of the point types I deal with is MFC/ATL's CPoint, which are hard-coded as `{ long x; long y; }`, with no useful typedefs of this sort.

Comment: @martin_ljchan: See the second solution!

Comment: @martin_ljchan: You can start from here: [Traits: a new and useful template technique](http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html) **by Nathan C. Myers**. I think it was him who first described this technique. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a traits style approach to this:

```
template<typename T> struct DeterminantReturnInfo {};  
template<> struct DeterminantReturnInfo<MyType> { typedef MyOtherType ReturnType; }

template< typename T >
typename DeterminantReturnInfo<T>::ReturnType Determinant( const P & a, const P & B, const P & c)
{
  return  (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (c.x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y);
}
```

If you want it to default to double then you just add `typedef double ReturnType;` to the initial template.

Comment: `typedef ReturnType double;`? Wrong syntax

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. (Though its an obvious typo that you could have corrected with the edit button)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or GCC 4.5+, you can use the trailing return type form:

```
template<class P>
auto fun(const P& a) -> decltype(a.x + a.y){
  return a.x + a.y;
}
```

Thanks to `decltype` we automatically get the right return type. Also, the computation is still only done once in the body, not in the trailing return.

Answer (score 0):

Check your return Type its of type member variable  x/y . You might not returning so type T.